# Passing complex arrays into a function, getting incorrect answer back

Tags: arrays, function, fortran

I'm currently trying to make a genetic algorithm, to find some possible solutions to a problem I want to solve. I have created a complex array using random number generation which I pass through to my function which normalizes the array, with my code looking like;

```
PROGRAM genetic_algorithm

IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER:: a, b
INTEGER :: i,j
REAL :: d,e
INTEGER, DIMENSION(8) :: seed
COMPLEX,DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: pop_mat, norm_mat
COMPLEX :: c, norm


WRITE(*,*) "Input Seed values - 8"
READ(*,*) seed
WRITE(*,*) "Input state vector number"
READ(*,*) b
WRITE(*,*) "Input population number"
READ(*,*) a

ALLOCATE(pop_mat(a,b))
ALLOCATE(norm_mat(a,b))

OPEN(1,FILE='Candidate_solutions.txt')
CALL RANDOM_SEED(PUT=seed)

DO i = 1,a
    DO j = 1,b
        CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(d)
        CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(e)
        d = (2*d) -1
        e = (2*e) - 1
        c = CMPLX(d,e)
        pop_mat(i,j)=c
        WRITE(1,'(2F9.5)',advance='no') pop_mat(i,j)
    END DO
    WRITE(1,*) ''
END DO
CLOSE(1)
norm_mat=norm(pop_mat,a,b)
WRITE(*,*) norm_mat(:,:)
END PROGRAM genetic_algorithm
```

I have the final write command, to test the output. My `norm` function looks like this:

```
COMPLEX FUNCTION norm(x,y,z)
IMPLICIT NONE

COMPLEX, DIMENSION(y,z), INTENT(INOUT) :: x
INTEGER, INTENT (IN) :: y, z
REAL :: norm_val
REAL, DIMENSION(y) :: state_sum
INTEGER :: i, j

OPEN(2,FILE='norm_mat.txt')
DO i = 1, y
    DO j =1, z
        norm_val = CONJG(x(i,j))*x(i,j)
        state_sum(i) = state_sum(i) + norm_val
    END DO
END DO

DO i = 1, y
    DO j =1, z
        x(i,j) = (1/SQRT(state_sum(i)))*x(i,j)
        WRITE(2,'(2F9.5)',advance='no') x(i,j)
    END DO
    WRITE(2,*) ''
END DO
CLOSE(2)
WRITE(*,*) x(:,:)
WRITE(*,*) ''
END FUNCTION
```

The `FUNCTION norm`, it outputs the correct values to `norm_mat.txt`, but when passed back through to the main program, I get every matrix element equal to `( 2.34180515E-38,  0.0000000  )`. I have tried messing with the allocations, and only passing through the matrix, then allocating them with `size(a,1) size(a,2)` but I could not allocate the size of `state_sum` using that method, as it kept giving an error.

I can't understand why it won't pass back the correct value.

Comment: `norm` has scalar function result. Is this what you expect? Perhaps not, as you don't define its value, and you have it as the right-hand side of assignment to an array.

Comment: Ok there must be something im not understanding about functions. I want the function to take my matrix pop_mat and normalise it, then return an array of the same dimensions to the main program, so i can then use the normalised function for other functions.

Comment: doesn't your compiler complain about the return value never being set?

Comment: Please use the `newunit` specifier instead of hard coding file identification units. This will improve your code's portability.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the function in a wrong way. The compiler cannot help you too much because the function is external. You should place it in a module and the compiler will be able to help you more by complaining in case of certain errors. You should also enable compiler warnings (`-Wall` in gfortran or `-warn` in Intel Fortran).

In particular:

1. You have an `intent(inout)` argument in a function. That is allowed, but can be somewhat confusing, consider using a subroutine instead. Are you sure you didn't want to use `x` as a result?
2. The value of the function result is not set anywhere in the `norm` function. That is a serious problem. There should be a line

   ```
   norm = something
   ```

   somewhere in the function, probably at the end.
3. The function returns a single complex number (scalar), but you assign the (unset!) result to an array `norm_mat`. Is `norm_mat` supposed to be an array or rather a scalar? You must make it consistent. If you actually want to return an array that the function should be in a module.
4. You assume that the seed array has size `8`. This is compiler dependent. You should get the size of the array by calling `RANDOM_SEED` first, there are some examples on this site.
5. You are using unit number `2` for your file opening. It is dangerous, small numbers are often reserved for some special purpose. Use numbers above 10. Fortran 2008 has the `newunit=` specifier instead.

Comment: Ok I will use the -Wall from now on.
1) I want to input the matrix from the main program and normalise it, then get the normalised array passed back, is this not how its achieved?
2) What do I assign norm too? I am normalising my matrix mat, shouldnt that be the output?
3) Why is it outputing a single complex number? I dont actually understand what is giving the output in my function.
4) I did this because i will be using the same compiler every time. I will rectify that with the random(seed)
5) I have changed these to 10 and 11, and will use values above this from now on.

Thanks!

Comment: You must understand what a function does and how it differs from a subroutine. It seems to me you are confused in this. I can't repeat that in this small place, you should read some textbook or tutorial. You can start here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/1106/procedures-functions-and-subroutines#t=201611011644068779987

Comment: And again, if you really want the function to return an array, it **must** be in a module and you will have to delete `COMPLEX :: NORM` from the main program. (You should do it and move the function to a module anyway.)

Comment: Ok i will read up, but im guessing this should be in a subroutine to make it easier?

Comment: It depends on you. But think also whether you do or do not want to change the content of the original matrix you are passing to norm or whether you just want to make a copy that is normalized.

Comment: I just want to normalise it, and then return it so i can pass it to another function/subroutine.

Comment: A subroutine will be easier for you (but function is also possible).

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense switching horses mid stream going from subroutine to function or visa versa,.
And I am heavily editing the answer since it seems to be vexing.

I use this to remember my way around this stuff.:
https://xkcd.com/849/

Basically CONJG takes in a complex and returns a complex.
Norm_Val is real. A complex should not be forced into a scalar.

Therefore this segment looks totally dodgy...

```
DO i = 1, y
  DO j =1, z
    norm_val = CONJG(x(i,j))*x(i,j)
    state_sum(i) = state_sum(i) + norm_val
  END DO
END DO
```

You either want:

```
norm_val = REAL(CONJG(x(i,j))*x(i,j))
```

or

```
norm_val = (x(i,j)**2)**0.5
```

or

```
norm_val = ABS(x(i,j))
```

I would suggest maybe the last one.

And initialise state_sum, check for state_sum(i)=0 before you divid 1.0 by a state_ norm which is zero.

I start with an elemental core that you verify, and then accrete more code around it in a layered development approach. Do not try to eat a horse in one byte.

Comment: Yeah I was mixing languages, so 1/2 ifort and have a scripting language., I sorted it out.

Comment: sorry @holmz, this is a whole lot of stuff that doesn't even address the problem he's having with returning the result to the calling unit .

Comment: If the basic problem may be in the complex into a real, then there has been a lot of chaff about functions versus subroutines, and other style-points, which are orthogonal to the basic problem.

Comment: Orthogonal? He didn't even know how to return a value from a function. He was just returning an undefined scalar value and assigning to an array,

Comment: Yah are correct in that there are a few problems... It seems little is written about debugging cider ( or I need to look )